# Importing data to a database in DBeaver reaches only 10,1 Gb (thou it should be 25 Gb) and then the script goes on forever

Tags: database, csv, import, dbeaver, ventura

I create database in DBeaver and import the data from csv files according to file load.sql.
I use script IMPORT DATABASE '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb'
The database reaches only 10,1 Gb thou should be 25 Gb and the script goes on without end.
Please help to understand how to solve that problem?

I use MacOS Ventura 13.4.1, MacBook Pro M1 chip.

COPY titles_genres FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/titles_genres.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY episodes FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/episodes.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY persons FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/persons.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY ratings FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/ratings.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY title_person_character FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/title_person_character.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY titles FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/titles.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY cast_info FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/cast_info.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');
COPY persons_professions FROM '/Users/craigue/anaconda3/envs/imdb_duckdb/persons_professions.csv' (FORMAT 'csv', header 0, delimiter ',', quote '"');

I tried different locations of the database, it doesn't matter.
I expect that all the data is imported to the database as it should be according to instructions from edx course AI Skills for Engineers: Data Engineering and Data Pipelines